# Android: Time going backwards error

Tags: android, multithreading

I know there was a similar question, but this one is different:

When running my app, I get thousands of this error!
This is every few milliseconds, when I call:

```
long curTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

This is called from a loop in a thread:

```
private class LedAnimatorThread extends Thread {
@Override
public void run() {
    //...
    while(!mStopped) {
        long curTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    }
}
```

Why does it happen and how can I prevent this?

**EDIT:**
Sorry I totally forgot to post the warning message which appears on the log.
It is similar to this one:

> /SystemClock(11814): time going backwards: prev 9003590393023(ioctl) vs now 9003584533648(ioctl), tid=11856

Comment: Why do you need to call this function so often? Making a system call like this every few milliseconds is a lot.

Comment: I need to do sth at an exact interval. So I need to transmit something every say 17 milliseconds. I don't really see another way currently

Comment: Nevermind, I was confusing it for a different function.

Comment: What is the error that you receive? And are you calling this method every few milliseconds or are you receiving error because of this line?

Comment: I'm not sure how what you're saying can happen, as [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) for `elapsedRealtime()` say that  "This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic".

Comment: btw: The error seems not to appear when I put "synchronized" around the system call. Although I cannot verify for sure now.

Answer (score 0):

You have got any error imfomation?  Maybe you can use the TimerTask class to deal whit you task. 
And don't creating a new variable in while loop. It will waste a lot of memory. like this:

```
long curTime;
while(!mStopped) {
    curTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
}
```